# VTK inheritance Issue

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtk

I'm currently trying to customize the c++ android native example so as to be able to change the behaviour of what happens when interacting with 2 (or 3) fingers when using the tablet. From what I've understood with the VTK Pipeline I should therefore modify the behaviour of the vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor (correct me if I'm wrong though).
So this is what I have so far:

*myRenderInteractor.h*

```
#include "vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor.h"

#include "vtkRenderingOpenGL2Module.h" // For export macro
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"


#ifndef LOGI
  #define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NativeVTK", __VA_ARGS__))
#endif
#ifndef LOGW
  #define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "NativeVTK", __VA_ARGS__))
#endif



class myRenderInteractor : public vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor {
    public:
        static myRenderInteractor *New();
        vtkTypeMacro(myRenderInteractor, vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor);
        void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent);
        void log();

    protected:
    myRenderInteractor();
    ~myRenderInteractor();
};
```

*myRenderInteractor.cxx*

```
#include "myRenderInteractor.h"

vtkStandardNewMacro(myRenderInteractor);

myRenderInteractor::myRenderInteractor(){
    vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor();
}

~myRenderInteractor::myRenderInteractor(){
    ~vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor();
}

void myRenderInteractor::log(){
    // ...
}
```

And finally in the *main.cxx*

```
#include "vtkNew.h"

#include "vtkActor.h"
#include "vtkCamera.h"
#include "vtkConeSource.h"
#include "vtkDebugLeaks.h"
#include "vtkGlyph3D.h"
#include "vtkPolyData.h"
#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkSphereSource.h"
#include "vtkTextActor.h"
#include "vtkTextProperty.h"

#include "myRenderInteractor.h"
#include "vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor.h"

#include <android/log.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>

#ifndef LOGI
  #define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NativeVTK", __VA_ARGS__))
#endif
#ifndef LOGW
  #define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "NativeVTK", __VA_ARGS__))
#endif

/**
 * This is the main entry point of a native application that is using
 * android_native_app_glue.  It runs in its own thread, with its own
 * event loop for receiving input events and doing other things.
 */
void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{
  // Make sure glue isn't stripped.
  app_dummy();

  vtkNew<vtkRenderWindow> renWin;
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
  vtkNew<myRenderInteractor> iren;

  // this line is key, it provides the android
  // state to VTK
  iren->SetAndroidApplication(state);

  renWin->AddRenderer(renderer.Get());
  iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin.Get());

  vtkNew<vtkSphereSource> sphere;
  sphere->SetThetaResolution(8);
  sphere->SetPhiResolution(8);

  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> sphereMapper;
  sphereMapper->SetInputConnection(sphere->GetOutputPort());
  vtkNew<vtkActor> sphereActor;
  sphereActor->SetMapper(sphereMapper.Get());

  vtkNew<vtkConeSource> cone;
  cone->SetResolution(6);

  vtkNew<vtkGlyph3D> glyph;
  glyph->SetInputConnection(sphere->GetOutputPort());
  glyph->SetSourceConnection(cone->GetOutputPort());
  glyph->SetVectorModeToUseNormal();
  glyph->SetScaleModeToScaleByVector();
  glyph->SetScaleFactor(0.25);

  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> spikeMapper;
  spikeMapper->SetInputConnection(glyph->GetOutputPort());

  vtkNew<vtkActor> spikeActor;
  spikeActor->SetMapper(spikeMapper.Get());

  renderer->AddActor(sphereActor.Get());
  renderer->AddActor(spikeActor.Get());
  renderer->SetBackground(0.4,0.5,0.6);

  vtkNew<vtkTextActor> ta;
  ta->SetInput("Droids Rock");
  ta->GetTextProperty()->SetColor( 0.5, 1.0, 0.0 );
  ta->SetDisplayPosition(50,50);
  ta->GetTextProperty()->SetFontSize(32);
  renderer->AddActor(ta.Get());

  renWin->Render();
  iren->Start();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I have the following error. So maybe I just stupidly forgot something really simple but I just can't find why I get it.

> /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/Common/Core/vtkNew.h:66: error:
>   undefined reference to 'myRenderInteractor::New()' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make[3]: ***
>
> [Examples/Android/NativeVTK/libs/armeabi-v7a/libNativeVTK.so] Error 1
>   make[2]: ***
>
> [Examples/Android/NativeVTK/jni/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK.dir/all] Error 2
>   make[1]: ***
>
> [Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule]
>   Error 2 make: ***
>
> [Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule]
>   Error 2

Would love to get some help on that.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** In my Makefile in Examples/Android/NativeVTK/ I have:

```
# Convenience name for target.
Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/rule:
    cd /Users/lonnibesancon/Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/rule
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/rule

# Convenience name for target.
NativeVTK-ant-configure: Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/rule
.PHONY : NativeVTK-ant-configure

# fast build rule for target.
NativeVTK-ant-configure/fast:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/build.make Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-ant-configure.dir/build
.PHONY : NativeVTK-ant-configure/fast

# Convenience name for target.
Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/rule:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/rule
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/rule

# Convenience name for target.
NativeVTK-apk-debug: Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/rule
.PHONY : NativeVTK-apk-debug

# fast build rule for target.
NativeVTK-apk-debug/fast:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/build.make Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/build
.PHONY : NativeVTK-apk-debug/fast

# Convenience name for target.
Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule

# Convenience name for target.
NativeVTK-apk-release: Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/rule
.PHONY : NativeVTK-apk-release

# fast build rule for target.
NativeVTK-apk-release/fast:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(MAKE) -f Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/build.make Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-release.dir/build
.PHONY : NativeVTK-apk-release/fast
```

So I thought that I should check the build.make which contains:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.1

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.2/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.2/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android

# Utility rule file for NativeVTK-apk-debug.

# Include the progress variables for this target.
include Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/progress.make

Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/Examples/Android/NativeVTK && /usr/local/bin/ant -file /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/Examples/Android/NativeVTK/build.xml debug

NativeVTK-apk-debug: Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug
NativeVTK-apk-debug: Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/build.make
.PHONY : NativeVTK-apk-debug

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/build: NativeVTK-apk-debug
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/build

Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/clean:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/Examples/Android/NativeVTK && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -P CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/clean

Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/depend:
    cd /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/Examples/Android/NativeVTK /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/.../Android/NativeVTK /Users/.../Desktop/VTKNew/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/.../Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=$(COLOR)
.PHONY : Examples/Android/NativeVTK/CMakeFiles/NativeVTK-apk-debug.dir/depend
```

Is that the file that I need to change. Quite frankly I am completely lost and would love to get some more documentation on the overall process since I cannot use cmake for some reason. Of course I would prefer not to have to resort to modifying the makefile directly but it would seem that I have no choice for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have defined myRenderInteractor in a library, but then forgotten to link your executable to that library via target_link_libraries.

According to the error output in your question, you're getting an "undefined reference" error from ld -- that's a linker error. Your code compiles just fine. You need to add the library which contains myRenderInteractor to the list of libraries linked into your final executable. If you are not using CMake to generate the makefiles involved, then you need to add the library name to the list of things linked in your hand-crafted make file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I do that in the Makefile? Cause I'm using the Makefile generated automatically when building vtk as I have problems ccmake-ing directly the examples by myself

Comment: Wouldn't it get me a problem even before that? Like when simply trying to include the header?

Comment: Answered as an edit to my answer... (yes, do that in the Makefile and no, you wouldn't get a problem before that - if you include the header file, then it's defined when you're compiling... but if you don't link to it, then it's not defined when you're linking...)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I completely understand now but I have some problems when it comes to actually editing the makefile. I could use some help if you don't mind (see edit). Indeed I cannot use CMake without getting into this error when it comes to android examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099009/vtk-for-android

Comment: Edit done. Thanks again for the help you have provided so far

Comment: So, wait. You're not using CMake, but you're using a CMake-generated Makefile ... ? I'm confused.

Comment: Is there a CMakeLists.txt file, or not?

Comment: Yes I'm using a CMake generated make file because when building VTK I chose the build example option and the examples were built just fine but I try to CMake myself on the android examples I get the error mentioned above (see link to the other SO post). Therefore, while waiting for a solution to this problem or an integration with android studio I thought this was a good way of doing things just to keep myself busy and get back to that problem afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92984/discussion-between-lbesancon-and-dlrdave).